# Is there any replacement for Webmin file manager?

Tags: centos, webmin, file-manager, controlpanel

I was wondering if there is any third party module to replace Webmin Java file manager. I couldn't find anything in Webmin website. so is there anything I can try?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, java applets are not supported in Android devices but sometimes you simply need to quickly edit a file on your server (webmin) on the go from your mobile / smart phone for example and you are done. It will never work... There are hacks, cracks and all sorts of "unofficial" stuff but this is not what I prefer. It would be great to replace java-applets based file manager in webmin for let's say php file manager that would have the same or at least half of the functionality to be able to edit files on the go in webmin...  Webmin on computer = java applets file manager, Webmin on Android devices = something else that works.

Comment: Good prefer,but not answer.